# Seleccionar las últimas 10 entradas de MySQL y ordenarlas

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas,

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código para ordenar en función del número de visitas artículos que están dentro de una tabla de MySQL:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM art ORDER BY visitas DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Sin embargo, no es esto lo que quiero, de esta forma me ordena TODAS las entradas que tenga en la tabla, pero de nada me sirve tener artículos de hace 2 años por ejemplo en la sección de lo más visto. Quería saber si es posible a la hora de hacer la petición, seleccionar las 10 últimas entradas y ordenarlas por el número de visitas, en vez de que lo primero que haga sea ordenar todas las entradas por el número de visitas y después seleccionarme las 10 primeras.

Comment: al parecer todo mundo asume que tu tabla tiene un atributo fecha. Si lo tiene, entonces las respuestas si te servirán, pero si no, no hay forma de ordenarlas como lo quieres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Quería saber si es posible a la hora de hacer la petición, seleccionar las 10 últimas entradas y ordenarlas por el número de visitas.

Aunque la respuesta de Lamak es buena, me parece que de forma muy sutil, no hace lo que pides. Porque el resultado final estará ordenado por fecha, no por visitas.

Para que obtengas los últimos 10 registros, y luego ordenar esos 10 registros por visitas debes usar la consulta siguiente:

```
select *
  from (select *
          from art
         order by fecha desc
         limit 10) t
 order by visitas desc
```

Comment: Exacto, esta es la respuesta correcta, +1. Uno de los ejemplos del por qué esperar al menos 15 minutos antes de seleccionar una respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Efectivamente, ¡muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente debes agregar la condición de ordenar por fecha en tu `ORDER BY` :

```
SELECT *
FROM art
ORDER BY Fecha DESC, visitas DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Suponiendo que `Fecha` es el nombre de la columna con la fecha de la visita.

Comment: Solucionado, ¡muchísimas gracias!

Comment: @JetLagFox no olvides marcar como aceptada la pregunta pulsando el *tick* a la izq de la respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Tengo que esperar todavía 10 minutos para hacerlo :)

Comment: HAHAHA perdona @JetLagFox siempre lo olvido.

Comment: Perdona, pensaba que estaba solucionado pero veo que sólo me lo ordena por la fecha de publicación, la segunda condición para ordenarlo (visitas), lo obvia. Estoy usando: `$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM art ORDER BY fecha_publicacion DESC, visitas DESC LIMIT 5");`